# PHP Order by in paginated table from database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I got it to  order by but now the paginaging doesn't work. NOTHING prints into my error_logs now.

User Red Acid helpedme out with the the missing Whitespace and use a string variable instead of PHP_SELF.

Once I press next record I get:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /surf/$index.php was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

My code:

```
<?php
                $dbHost = "localhost";
                $dbUser = "";
                $dbPass = "";
                $dbName = "";
                $tbl_name="";
                $rec_limit = 20;
                $order = "ORDER BY";
                $scriptname = 'index.php';

                mysql_connect("$dbHost", "$dbUser", "$dbPass")or die("cannot connect");
                mysql_select_db("$dbName")or die("cannot select DB");


                $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name $order ".$_GET["orderby"]." ".$_GET["desc"];
                $result=mysql_query($sql);
                $sql = "SELECT count(steamid) FROM $tbl_name";
                    $result= mysql_query($sql);

                    if(! $result)
                    {
                       die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
                    }
                $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM );
                $rec_count = $row[0];

                if( isset($_GET{'page'} ) )
                {
                    $page = $_GET{'page'} + 1;
                    $offset = $rec_limit * $page ;
                }
                else
                {
                    $page = 0;
                    $offset = 0;
                }
                $left_rec = $rec_count - ($page * $rec_limit);
                $sql = "SELECT * ".
                "FROM $tbl_name ".
                "$order points DESC ".
                "LIMIT $offset, $rec_limit";
                $result=mysql_query($sql);
                while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $rows['name']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $rows['points']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $rows['winratio']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $rows['pointsratio']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $rows['finishedmaps']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $rows['lastseen']; ?></td>
                </tr>
                </tr>
                <?php
                }
                if( $page > 0 )
                     {
                        $last = $page - 2;
                        echo "<a href=\"$scriptname?page=$last\">Last 10 Records</a> |";
                        echo "<a href=\"$scriptname?page=$page\">Next 10 Records</a>";
                     }

                     else if( $page == 0 )
                     {
                        echo "<a href=\"$$scriptname?page=$page\">Next 10 Records</a>";
                        }

                     else if( $left_rec < $rec_limit )
                     {
                        $last = $page - 2;
                        echo "<a href=\"$$scriptname?page=$last\">Last 10 Records</a>";
                     }
                mysql_close();
                ?><?php
                $dbHost = "localhost";
                $dbUser = "c1226125_ms";
                $dbPass = "wR(@ucrb5oG.";
                $dbName = "c1226125_timer";
                $tbl_name="ck_playerrank";
                $rec_limit = 20;
                $order = "ORDER BY";
                $scriptname = 'index.php';

                mysql_connect("$dbHost", "$dbUser", "$dbPass")or die("cannot connect");
                mysql_select_db("$dbName")or die("cannot select DB");


                $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name $order ".$_GET["orderby"]." ".$_GET["desc"];
                $result=mysql_query($sql);
                $sql = "SELECT count(steamid) FROM $tbl_name";
                    $result= mysql_query($sql);

                    if(! $result)
                    {
                       die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
                    }
                $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM );
                $rec_count = $row[0];

                if( isset($_GET{'page'} ) )
                {
                    $page = $_GET{'page'} + 1;
                    $offset = $rec_limit * $page ;
                }
                else
                {
                    $page = 0;
                    $offset = 0;
                }
                $left_rec = $rec_count - ($page * $rec_limit);
                $sql = "SELECT * ".
                "FROM $tbl_name ".
                "$order points DESC ".
                "LIMIT $offset, $rec_limit";
                $result=mysql_query($sql);
                while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $rows['name']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $rows['points']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $rows['winratio']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $rows['pointsratio']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $rows['finishedmaps']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $rows['lastseen']; ?></td>
                </tr>
                </tr>
                <?php
                }
                if( $page > 0 )
                     {
                        $last = $page - 2;
                        echo "<a href=\"$scriptname?page=$last\">Last 10 Records</a> |";
                        echo "<a href=\"$scriptname?page=$page\">Next 10 Records</a>";
                     }

                     else if( $page == 0 )
                     {
                        echo "<a href=\"$$scriptname?page=$page\">Next 10 Records</a>";
                        }

                     else if( $left_rec < $rec_limit )
                     {
                        $last = $page - 2;
                        echo "<a href=\"$$scriptname?page=$last\">Last 10 Records</a>";
                     }
                mysql_close();
                ?>
```

Comment: Can you share which lines are producing these errors?

Comment: They're in the quotes.

Comment: Is it `$_GET` ? or `$_POST` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem that you dont have white space between ORDER BY and DESC:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name ORDER BY ".$_GET["orderby"].$_GET["desc"];
```

should be:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name ORDER BY ".$_GET["orderby"]." ".$_GET["desc"];
```

use string variable instead of PHP_SELF:

```
$scriptname = 'myscript.php'; // OR http://domain.com/myscript.php
echo "<a href=\"$scriptname?page=$last\">Last 10 Records</a>";
```

Comment: Got the order to work, But now i can't seem to get the paginagion to work now, No errors in the log now.

Check the main post, I edited it.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it to work :) Thank you sir i had two $$ in a variable, which was bugging, Can't believe i didn't see that :P